# erro em argumento timestamp python

Tags: python, pandas

Estou convertendo um conjunto da datas e tentando plotar um grafico com os valores convertidos mas estou com o erro a seguir, alguem sabe o que pode ser?

```
dates = data['data']
date_format = [pd.to_datetime(d) for d in dates]

rolling_average_days = 7
data['nuovi_positivi_moving'] = data['nuovi_positivi'].rolling(window=rolling_average_days).mean()
variable = 'nuovi_positivi_moving'
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 5))
ax.grid()
ax.scatter(date_format,data[variable])
ax.set(xlabel="Date",ylabel=variable,title='NOVOS CASOS POSITIVOS')
date_form = DateFormatter("%d-%m")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_form)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator(interval = 3))
fig.savefig(variable + '.png')
plt.show()
```

e o erro que retorna é o seguinte

> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not
> 'Timestamp'

Answer (score 0):

O problema está na transformação o `pd.to_datetime(d)` cria um objeto Timestamp , porem nesse seu caso seria mais válido um objeto DateTime então para isso basta você:
importar o datetime

```
from datetime import datetime
```

e alterar essa linha de transformação:

```
date_format = [datetime.strptime(d, '%d/%m/%y')for d in dates]
```